# Multiple nameservers with only one DNS.. workaround possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a VPS with Godaddy + cPanel and I would like to create my own private nameservers. Since I only have one server with Godaddy, I have only one DNS. Thus if I create 2 nameservers with the DNS of my server, I guess it's simply useless because if the DNS of my server goes down, my 2 nameservers are down too !

That's why I always create my nameservers with my domain registrar. However, how can I be sure that my domain registrar is not doing the same (creating my nameservers on the same DNS) ? Because if it's the case, what is the purpose of having multiple nameservers ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, how can I be sure that my domain registrar is not doing the same (creating my nameservers on the same DNS)?

You can't. But you either will be trusting their expertise to get the DNS service right or have a service description for the DNS service which would include express warranties that  DNS servers in different geographical and network-logical locations are used for hosting your zones.

If a hoster's DNS servers are in different [ASes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29) and under different TLDs, this generally is a good sign.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that your registrar/DNS provider NS records using [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig).

```
dig ns example.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  b.iana-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
b.iana-servers.net. 1768    IN  A   199.43.133.53
b.iana-servers.net. 1576    IN  AAAA    2001:500:8d::53
a.iana-servers.net. 187 IN  A   199.43.132.53
a.iana-servers.net. 1576    IN  AAAA    2001:500:8c::53

...
```

This will tell you which systems are configured as the name servers for your domain and what their IP addresses are.  The nameservers themselves may be single machines or they may be HA clusters containing multiple machines in multiple geographic locations, they could even be a single machine with 2 IP addresses it's really hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

When you register your nameserver(s) with your registrar, you provide 2 IP addresses. If you only have one server,  use that address as your primary...and then use GoDaddy as your secondary. You will need to update the records on your server, and with  GoDaddy to make sure they are identical.

Comment: So basically I use the DNS of my server + the DNS of my domain registrar ?

Comment: Yup. Though running a nameserver yourself may prove to be quite challenging, especially considering the cost:reward ratio. Is there a specific reason you want to run your own nameserver? Many companies these days are offloading this to either the registrar or another third party DNS service. They generally provide better uptime, faster responses, and are easier to manage. You seem to be going the opposite way

Comment: I just want to have my own personal nameservers… I don’t care if I manage my DNS or not.

Comment: So, you just want it to say ns1/ns2.yourdomain.com when they whois the domain, but you really don't care about who hosts it?

Comment: Exactly... but I want to be sure that they are hosted correctly !

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of other sites around that will provide a free (primary or secondary) DNS server for you to use. I used to use xname quite a lot, they have DNS servers spread around the world plus you get some amount of control of your zone.

http://www.xname.org/